# jquery ハンバーガーメニューの中のメニューの一つを押したとき

Tags: jquery, css

ハンバーガーメニューの中のメニューのうちのどれか一つを押してメニューを非表示にしつつ#ページに戻りたいです。

ハンバーガーメニューのアイコンを押せば非表示にできますが、メニューを押しても非表示になりません。ハンバーガーメニューは固定しています。
どなたかよろしくお願いします。

**ソースコード**

```
<div id="navigation">
        <div class="navigation_inner">
          <ul class="navigation_menu">
            <li class="navigation_item"><a href="#skills">SKILLS</a></li>
            <li class="navigation_item"><a href="#works">WORKS</a></li>
            <li class="navigation_item"><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>

          </ul>
        </div>
</div>


jQuery('.hamburger').on('click', function(){
    jQuery('#navigation').fadeToggle(600);
    jQuery("#skills").click(function(){
        jQuery('#navigation').fadeToggle(false);
    });
});
```

**実際の表示結果**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

メニューアイコンをclickした時の処理の中に、リストアイテムをクリックした場合のイベント登録が含まれてしまっているので、それぞれを分けると良いかと思います。

また、リストアイテムをクリックした場合のイベント登録は、アイテムが共通して持つ`navigation_item`classに対して行うと良いかと思います。

```
// メニューアイコンを押した時
jQuery('.hamburger').on('click', function(){
    jQuery('#navigation').fadeToggle(600);
});

// アイテムを押した時
jQuery('.navigation_item').on('click', function(){
    jQuery('#navigation').fadeOut();
});
```